# AWS SDK can not read environment variables

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am setting AWS_ env variables as below for Jenkins

```
    sudo apt-get update -y
    sudo apt-get install -y python3 python-pip python-devel
    sudo pip install awscli
    S3_LOGIN=$(aws sts assume-role --role-arn rolename --role-session-name s3_session)
    export AWS_CREDENTIAL_PROFILES_FILE=~/.aws/credentials
    export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(echo ${S3_LOGIN}| jq --raw-output '.Credentials|"\(.AccessKeyId)"')
    export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(echo ${S3_LOGIN} | jq --raw-output '.Credentials|"\(.SecretAccessKey)"')
    export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$(echo ${S3_LOGIN} | jq --raw-output '.Credentials|"\(.SessionToken)"')
    aws configure set default.region us-east-2
    aws configure set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    aws configure set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
```

But when I try to get them from code the sdk can not read the env variables already set

```
 AWSCredentials evc = new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider().getCredentials();
 AmazonS3Client amazonS3 = new AmazonS3Client(evc);
 amazonS3.setRegion(RegionUtils.getRegion("us-east-2"));
```

> com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials
>   from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and
>   AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY))

The EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider in AWS SDK looks below,

```
public AWSCredentials getCredentials() {
        String accessKey = System.getenv(ACCESS_KEY_ENV_VAR);
        if (accessKey == null) {
            accessKey = System.getenv(ALTERNATE_ACCESS_KEY_ENV_VAR);
        }

        String secretKey = System.getenv(SECRET_KEY_ENV_VAR);
        if (secretKey == null) {
            secretKey = System.getenv(ALTERNATE_SECRET_KEY_ENV_VAR);
        }

        accessKey = StringUtils.trim(accessKey);
        secretKey = StringUtils.trim(secretKey);
        String sessionToken =
            StringUtils.trim(System.getenv(AWS_SESSION_TOKEN_ENV_VAR));

        if (StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(accessKey)
                || StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(secretKey)) {

            throw new AmazonClientException(
                    "Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables " +
                    "(" + ACCESS_KEY_ENV_VAR + " (or " + ALTERNATE_ACCESS_KEY_ENV_VAR + ") and " +
                    SECRET_KEY_ENV_VAR + " (or " + ALTERNATE_SECRET_KEY_ENV_VAR + "))");
        }

        return sessionToken == null ?
                new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey)
                :
                new BasicSessionCredentials(accessKey, secretKey, sessionToken);
    }
```

---

EDIT: I try below approach also,

```
 ProfileCredentialsProvider  evc = new ProfileCredentialsProvider();
        AmazonS3Client amazonS3 = new AmazonS3Client(evc);
        amazonS3.setRegion(RegionUtils.getRegion("us-east-2"));
```

But even I set AWS_CREDENTIAL_PROFILES_FILE in the script because the credentials file is under ~/.aws/credentials, I still get below,

> credential profiles file not found in the given path:
>   /root/.aws/credentials

Even though the AwsProfileFileLocationProvider code says below, i am not sure why it try to look at /root/.aws/credentials

> Checks the environment variable override
>        * first, then checks the default location (~/.aws/credentials), and finally falls back to the
>        * legacy config file (~/.aws/config) that we still support loading credentials from

Comment: How are you running Jenkins? Single instance, agent based?

Comment: Please tell us how and where do you set the variables on Jenkins?

Comment: Actually, I realize by setting env variables via export, it does not set the env variables under /etc/environment. Problem is we dont have access to set env variables under /etc/environmnet too. The Jenkins runs on agent based

Comment: I run the above shell script from Execute shell in Jenkins Job

Comment: Why it runs as `root`? Maybe it's configure to do so https://jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/security/build-authorization/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are configuring your Jenkins Job with different build steps between set credential and consume credential.
Jenkins does not share environment variable between build steps.

If you are using old-style of Jenkins job you will need to use some Plugin like `envinject`, or use a file to share the variables between steps. Like below (just as example).

**Step 1**

```
echo "export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}" > credential
echo "export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}" >> credential
echo "export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=${AWS_SESSION_TOKEN}" >> credential
```

**Step 2**

```
source credential && ./your_command_here
```

---

But if you are suing Jenkins Pipeline, you can use `env`. Like below (just as example).

```
  pipeline {
        parameters {
            string(name: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', defaultValue: '')
        }

        stage("set credential") {
             steps {
               tmp_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID =  sh (script: 'your shell script here', returnStdout: true).trim()
               env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = tmp_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
              }
        }
        stage("consume credential") {
            steps {
              echo "${env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}"
            }
        }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks this make sense. I also checked the AWS SDK code. Its referring system env variables (/etc/environments) such as user.home which is the root in the jenkins

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to change the credentials file location using the [AWS_CREDENTIAL_PROFILES_FILE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/credentials.html#setting-an-alternate-credentials-file-location) environment variable