# Cannot read environment variables for AWS SDK while running Java application in Intellij

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, intellij-idea, aws-sdk

I am new to AWS SDK. I am trying to push data to Kinesis using the following code snippet:

```
      AmazonKinesisClientBuilder clientBuilder = AmazonKinesisClientBuilder.standard();
      clientBuilder.setCredentials(new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider());
      clientBuilder.setRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2.getName());

      AmazonKinesis kinesisClient = clientBuilder.build();

      PutRecordRequest putRecordRequest = new PutRecordRequest();
      putRecordRequest.setStreamName( "test" );
      putRecordRequest.setData(ByteBuffer.wrap( String.format( "testData-%d", 1 ).getBytes()));
      putRecordRequest.setPartitionKey( String.format( "partitionKey-%d", 1 ));
      PutRecordResult putRecordResult = kinesisClient.putRecord( putRecordRequest );

      System.out.println(putRecordResult.getSequenceNumber());
```

I have set following environment variables:

```
export AWS_PROFILE=default
export AWS_CREDENTIAL_PROFILES_FILE=~/.aws/credentials

export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=temp
export AWS_SECRET_KEY=temp
```

content of ~/.aws/config is as follows:

```
[default]
   region = us-west-2
```

and content of ~./aws/credentials is as follows:

```
[default]
   aws_access_key_id = temp
   aws_secret_access_key = temp
```

Now, while I am running the application in Intellij, I am getting following error in log:

```
Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or 
AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY))
```

In this context, I have gone through this: [AWS SDK can not read environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60354891/aws-sdk-can-not-read-environment-variables), but could not understand how to fix.

I have no idea, what I am missing here. Could anyone please help?

Comment: What OS do you use? Where do you set the environment variables? Are they visible in IntelliJ IDEA Terminal tool window if you run the `env` command there?

Comment: I have been able to fix this @CrazyCoder. I had to install AWS tool plugin for Intellij.

Comment: I just updated the AWS toolkit and It worked. Thank you for this @Joy

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this when assuming IAM roles, the fix being to ensure the AWS STS library is on the classpath. In SBT I resolved this by importing as a test dependency:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-sts" % awsSDKVersion % "test"
```